# Manage media player notification in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I have been able to stream audio from server and have also been able to show notification control when audio starts to play but the notification typically those nothing for now. My problem now is how to get the audio title and show it in the notification, so i tried this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class );
                intent.setAction(STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION );
                intent.putExtra("title",title);
                startService( intent );
```

i tried to send the title of the song to `NotificationService.class` when starting the notification service (the song is fetched from server according to the title of an item in my code) but I'm unable to receive it in `NotificationService.class`

This is my `NotificationService.class` and how i try to receive intent but it returns `null`

```
 private void showNotification() {

    createNotificationChanel();

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.status_bar);
    RemoteViews bigViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.status_bar_expanded);

    // trying to receive intent
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");


// showing default album image
    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_icon, View.VISIBLE);
    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_album_art, View.GONE);
    bigViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.status_bar_album_art,
            Constants.getDefaultAlbumArt(this));

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
    PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            previousIntent, 0);

    Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            playIntent, 0);

    Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            nextIntent, 0);

    Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    closeIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pcloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            closeIntent, 0);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);
    bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);
    bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);
    bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);
    bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);

    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
            R.drawable.apollo_holo_dark_pause);
    bigViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
            R.drawable.apollo_holo_dark_pause);

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, "Song Title");
    bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, "Song Title");

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, "Artist Name");
    bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, "Artist Name");

    bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_album_name, "Album Name");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        status = new Notification.Builder(this,CHANEL_ID).build();
    }
    status.contentView = views;
    status.bigContentView = bigViews;
    status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    status.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher_custom;
    status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to create media notification

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.image4); //replace with your own image


    // Create a new Notification

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            // Hide the timestamp
            .setShowWhen(false)
            // Set the Notification style
            .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    // Attach our MediaSession token
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    // Show our playback controls in the compat view
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            // Set the Notification color
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            // Set the large and small icons
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset)
            // Set Notification content information
            .setContentText("activeAudio.getArtist()")
            .setContentTitle("activeAudio.getAlbum()")
            .setContentInfo("activeAudio.getTitle()")
            // Add playback actions
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_replay_10_black_24dp, "previous", playbackAction(3))
            .addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_forward_10_black_24dp, "next", playbackAction(2));

    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```